# Differentiate between single and double click in React

Tags: reactjs

Trying to find out what is the best way of differentiating between single and double click in a React component.

The built-in [mouse events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events) (onClick and onDoubleClick) work fine if you don't want apply them on the same DOM element. There is the [jQuery dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) which I don't want to use. There is also a [React Timer Mixin](https://github.com/reactjs/react-timer-mixin) which could be used, but I use ES6 classes so then I would need to use something like [React Mixin](https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin) and I just think it's an overkill for doing such a simple thing.

From what I found out people would set the timeout on the click event, so I followed that direction and came with this:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Click extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      clickCount: 0
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    let clickCount = this.state.clickCount
    let singleClickTimer
    clickCount++

    this.setState({ clickCount: this.state.clickCount + 1 })

    if (clickCount === 1) {
      singleClickTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.state.clickCount === 1) {
          clickCount = 0
          this.setState({ clickCount: 0 })
          console.log('single click')
        }
      }, 300)
    } else if (clickCount === 2) {
      clearTimeout(singleClickTimer)
      clickCount = 0
      this.setState({ clickCount: 0 })
      console.log('double click')
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It works, but I'm trying to find out if there is a better way of doing it.

**Edit:**

The big problem with this is that `setTimeout` is async, so I added another check (`if (this.state.clickCount === 1) {`), but that seems wrong to me.

Another problem with this is the delay, the `double click` is called immediately, but the `single click` will be called after whatever timeout was set (around 300ms).

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but I spun my wheels on this problem a bit also, so thought I'd share my solution for those who also end up here.

```
const DOUBLECLICK_TIMEOUT = 300;

handleImagePress = () => {
  this.setState({ pressCount: this.state.pressCount+1 });

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.state.pressCount == 0) { return }

    if (this.state.pressCount == 1) {
      // Do single press action
    } else if (this.state.pressCount == 2) {
      // Do double press action
    }

    this.setState({ pressCount: 0 });
  }, DOUBLECLICK_TIMEOUT)
}
```